# Difference between BufferedReader and reading raw bytes from InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I am programming a software which needs to start another process, no problem here. I've written a small stream-redirecter (mostly called "Pump"), which reads from `System.in` and writes it to the "Process"es input-stream. When I read raw bytes from `System.in` I don't get any output in the command-window, so I don't see what I am writing, but the command gets redirected correctly. When I wrap the Stream with a `BufferedReader` and `readLine()`s, I see what I am writing, but the problem here is, keys like arrow-up, tab, and so on are not redirected.

So simple question, what does `BufferedReader` to show what I've typed? It can't be a simple sysout, otherwise the next log-line from the process would just get appended after what I've typed (while typing), what actually happens is, the next output from the process overwrites what I've written so far and I see my input again in the line after.

Comment: A `Reader` decodes the `byte` stream into `char`s, that is the difference. Also, what does your program do which `ProcessBuilder` doesn't?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. And your Question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It does, at it says what a `Reader` does vs an `InputStream`. As to my second question, read the javadoc of `ProcessBuilder`. This, or your question doesn't tell everything.

Comment: The ProcessBuilder only starts the process for me, it doesn't handle the streams. And my Question was, how the BufferedReader handles the stream differently so that i can still see what i'm typing while i can't when i read byte-by-byte.

Comment: Of course a `ProcessBuilder` can handle the streams. Did you see all the redirect possibilities `ProcessBuilder` has to offer?

Comment: Well yes, it can just redirect them to stdin/out/err, but then i can't log output or write to input. And i am not using `ProcessBuilder`, i am using a `org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor` from inside a maven-plugin, the `org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler` handles all three streams, but i can't see what i type. When i handle the inputstream myself with a `BufferedReader` i can see what i type.

Comment: "but then i can't log output or write to input" <-- yes you can. Java has `Piped{Input,Output}Stream`

Comment: You can log the output of a process with the [redirectOutput(File)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput-java.io.File-) method of ProcessBuilder.